# correctly deleting data from the heatmap plotly

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

Say I have a fully filled heatmap.

```
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(z=data.z_list,x=data.x_list,y=data.y_list))
fig.update_xaxes(range=[data.x_min,data.x_max])
fig.update_yaxes(range=[data.y_min,data.y_max])
```

And then I delete some data from my dataset expecting to see, for example, this picture
[image]

but instead I got this:
[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

- you have not defined your data structure or provided a way to simulate it.  I have assumed that *z_list, x_list and y_list* are **numpy** arrays
- if there are areas / slices you do not want to plot.  Just set them to `np.nan`

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
from types import SimpleNamespace

S = 200
data = {"z_list":np.random.uniform(0,1, [S,S]),"x_list":np.linspace(-3,4,S),"y_list":np.linspace(-1,1,S)}
data = SimpleNamespace(**data)
# delete.... well actually set to nan so it does not plot
data.z_list[:,20:30] = np.nan
data.z_list[:,35:37] = np.nan
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(z=data.z_list,x=data.x_list,y=data.y_list))
# fig.update_xaxes(range=[data.x_min,data.x_max])
# fig.update_yaxes(range=[data.y_min,data.y_max])

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Can't I do it without setting it to nan values?

Comment: don't know without you actually state your data or fully define your data structure   I've had a stab at implying it ...

Comment: You were right, z_list, x_list and y_list are numpy arrays

Comment: the only way I can replicate image you have shown if by doing a forward fill `fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(z=pd.DataFrame(data.z_list).fillna(method="ffill", axis=1).values,x=data.x_list,y=data.y_list))`. this implies you have not deleted anything from you array,  but have repeating values for y across a sequence of x